# Wildfly started to return UT000128: Remote peer closed connection before all data could be read

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, wildfly

We have a java application deployed on JBoss Wildfly on AWS (on EC2 instance with ELB).

Functionality of application is to upload files.

But suddenly without any change uploading started to fail with error:
"UT000128: Remote peer closed connection before all data could be read"

Can it be AWS problem? What can we do? 
Restarting of EC2 instance didn't help

```java
@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes({TEXT_CSV, APPLICATION_XLSX, APPLICATION_ZIP})
@Produces("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public Response postDataFile(InputStream is) {
   File file = null;
   try {
     file = File.createTempFile("prefix", "suffix");
     try (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
       byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
       int count;
       while ((count = is.read(buf)) != -1) { // Here exception is thrown
         os.write(buf, 0, count);
       }
     }
```

Exception is thrown in the line with: `is.read(buf)`

Comment: Did you tried to send data to your aws through postman? If so, same error?

Comment: Yes, the same through postman

Comment: It works only for tiny files less than 1MB.

Comment: Did you lookup for restrictions on aws? Maybe that is intended

Comment: Two days ago were no restrictions, and now there are some restrictions?

Comment: Application worked for couple of months without issues.

Comment: Did you used in these two days maybe files less than 1mb? Or maybe it's something to do with monthly bandwidth? I don't know much about aws instances. But if you didn't changed something on your instance, that would be my searching point to look up for any kind of restrictions.

Comment: Yes, we used large files before and it worked. No changes in aws configuration or ec2 instance.

Comment: @smalafeev Have you found any solution? My Log contains a lot of "UT000128: Remote peer closed connection before all data could be read"

Comment: @SebinThomas I fixed it on httpd side by adding  to httpd.conf:

    <IfModule reqtimeout_module>
  RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500
   </IfModule>